# how to get required records available in a table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get records in between a table based upon a condition using mysql. This is my table.
table name:trans_table  and it has two fields.

```
item    transaction
-----   -----------
item1   b
item2   b
item3   b
item3   c
item4   d
item5   b
```

I am trying to get item having only transaction b alone.So, result doesnot contain any other transaction. The required output will be like this

```
item   transaction
-----  -----------
item1   b
item2   b
item5   b
```

(becoz item3 having transaction c along with b and item 4 and item4 doesnot contain transaction b)

I tried with following queries

```
1.`select * from trans_tbl where transaction = 'b'`

2.`select item,qty from trans_tbl where item in(select item from trans_table group by    item having count(item)=1);`
```

with the above two queries I am unable to get my required output. So is any other way to get this?

Comment: What happens when you run your query? Do you get nothing at all? All the records? An error message? Are you running your query through PHP, or directly against the database?

Comment: Your first query should be working.  What is the definition of the table?  In particular, what is the type of transaction?

Comment: @GordonLinoff it won't work because he doesn't want item3 at all, and his first query will bring back item3 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.  It will group all the items together and only return items that 1. Have a single transaction and 2. That transaction is 'b'

```
select item, transaction
from trans_tbl
where transaction = 'b'
group by item, transaction
having count(item) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

another solution:

```
select distinct t1.item, t1.transaction
from trans_tbl t1
left join trans_tbl t2 on t1.name=t2.name and t1.transaction<>t2.transaction
where t2.name is null
```

Left join and checking right part for null will do the trick.